# I move my bone but when I go to a different frame it goes back to the origin

Tags: animation

I move my upper arm bone and the model follows it but when I change frames it reverts to what it was originally. Yes, I do have auto key on. It doesn't matter what keyframe I have it on, it goes back to the origin if I move it.

Picture 1: At the moment the bone is at the origin position.

Picture 2: I then move the bone to another position to see what it looks like.

Picture 3: I go to Frame one to see if the problem is still happening and yes it has gone back to the origin position.

Picture 4: I then go back to the frame I changed it on and it has gone back to the origin position.

Picture 5: The frame I was changing was the only one I had.

[image: At the moment the bone is at the origin position.]

[image: I then move the bone to another position to see what it looks like.]

[image: I go to Frame one to see if the problem is still happening and yes it has gone back to the origin position.]

[image: I then go back to the frame I changed it on and it has gone back to the origin position.]

[image: The frame I was changing was the only one I had.]

Comment: You have to add keyframes for the bones, what you transformed. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/keyframes/editing.html#insert-keyframes

Comment: @FFeller: post this as an answer, get some credit!